# Select box value copy to input at clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

SOS please help!
I have this selectbox and input:

Fruits:

```
<select size="10" name="category" id="category">
  <option value="f:apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="f:banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="f:mango">Mango</option>
  <option value="f:pear">Pear</option>
  <option value="f:orange">Orange</option>
</select>
<input id="whatilove" type="text">
```

I click more element /Apple, Mango/ the values copied to text input.
So, I click to Apple and Mango and the values copied to input: "f:apple f:mango"

Please save my life thank you!
Cheers!

Comment: What in the world are you asking?

Comment: _I click more element /Apple, Mango/ the values copyed to text input._ . What? And where is your question?

Comment: What would you `like` to happen?

Comment: Are you sure that you dont have a `multiple="true"` attribute in your select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of select menu and concat with the value of text input -

```
$('#category').on('change', function() {
    $('#whatilove').val($('#whatilove').val() + ' ' + $(this).val());
})
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/obbhstqw/)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you want:

You want the selected option text inside the textbox.

```
$('#category').on('change', function() {
    $('#whatilove').val($('#category option:selected').text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#category').change(function() {
    $('#whatilove').val($(this).val().join(' '));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<select size="10" name="category" id="category" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="f:apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="f:banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="f:mango">Mango</option>
  <option value="f:pear">Pear</option>
  <option value="f:orange">Orange</option>
</select>
<input id="whatilove" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to track selected value, if it is and have all those values in a text input. If so try this:

```
var selectedValues = [];
$("#category").change(function() {
    if($.inArray($(this).val(),selectedValues) === -1)
        selectedValues.push($(this).val());
    $('#whatilove').val(selectedValues.join(" "));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help you to avoide duplicate selection and add selected values only:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
$('#category').on('change', function() {

     previous_val=$('#whatilove').val();         
     arry_val=previous_val.split(",")              
     selected_val=$(this).val();         
     if(previous_val!="")
     {          
        if($.inArray(selected_val, arry_val)==-1)
        {
             $('#whatilove').val(previous_val + ',' + $(this).val());
        }
     }
     else
     {
        $('#whatilove').val( selected_val);
     }   

});
```

});

Thanks